# Current Ubuntu 19.10 kernel configuration

Tags: kernel, 19.10

I'm trying to build the Linux Kernel 5.4.7 in a multipass ubuntu 16.04 for Ubuntu 19.10.

*NB : I'm running a post-2018 MacBook Pro with MacOsX Catalina so I need this particular kernel, because it has the required patches : https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.4.7&id=66341331ba0d2de4ff421cdc401a1e34de50502a*).

**My question is : where can I find the configuration of the current kernel used in Ubuntu 19.10 ?**

Comment: Why don't you get the 5.4.7 kernel already compiled here https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4.7/

Comment: If you look in `/boot` you'll find one or more files that look like `config-5.3.0-24-generic` (the numbers will vary based on your system). Just copy that file to one named "config", and use that to build the new kernel.

Comment: @heynnema I'm working with MacOs Catalina or Ubuntu 16.04 (with multipass), so I won't find any adequate /boot

Comment: @Pilot6 Will it work with Ubuntu 19.10 ? I'm sorry, I'm new at this

Comment: From Ubuntu 16.04 (do you mean 19.10?) you don't see a /boot directory? I don't know what multipass (*unless you're referring to the movie The Fifth Element* :-) ) is.

Comment: https://multipass.run/ is a canonical project to emul Ubuntu in Windows or MacOS (I actually don't really understand how it works, but it does :-) ), which runs "only" Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. So, if I take the Ubuntu 16.04 (or 18.04) /boot/config-*kernelversion*-generic file, and build my kernel (5.4.7) with this config, will it works for Ubuntu 19.10 ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think you have to rename it to `config`... but if you're planning on running this on 19.10, why don't you build it on 19.10, or download the pre-built binary as @Pilot6 indicates... it may not have the patch that you desire though...